# nested attributes for registration form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a user and a company model where a user has_one company and company belongs to user. I just wanted to save the company field from the registration form to the company table,where the company table columns are user_id and company_name. I used the following to do this in my User.rb

```
      has_one :company, :class_name => 'Company', :foreign_key => :user_id, :dependent => :destroy
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :company
```

And My registration form looks like this

```
           <h2>Sign up</h2>
  <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>               

<%= devise_error_messages! %>

<p><%= f.label :firstname %><br/>
  <%= f.text_field :firstname %></p>

<p><%= f.label :lastname %><br/>
  <%= f.text_field :lastname %></p>

<p><%= f.label :email %><br/>
  <%= f.email_field :email %></p>

<p><%= f.label :password %><br/>
  <%= f.password_field :password %></p>

<p><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br/>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></p>

<%= fields_for :company do |builder| %>
    <%= builder.label :company %>
    <td><%= builder.text_field :company_name%> </td>
<% end %>

<p><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></p>
<% end %>

<%= render :partial => "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Is it necessary to have a hidden field for user_id for company table or it will get automatically added, I also tried overriding the create method of registration controller it works but the devise error messages are not working. Can anyone help me out in this. I dont know what I have missed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) No, you don't need a user_id hidden field, just use fields_for as a method

```
<%= f.fields_for :company do |builder| %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

2) fields_for will not be shown if user does not have associated companies yet, and that will happen with new record, so you can do 
`<% f.object.company.build %>` as a hack :)
or do it the proper way in a controller action

Comment: alony do I need to have a seperate controller for company model till now i have not created one I am using devise for user registration and I have oly created the fields_for in my view.

Comment: no, definitely not. Actually you can do that in User model, in callback:
`def after_initialize {|record| record.company.build if record.company.empty? }`

Comment: thank you alony the mistake which i did was I didnt set the company_attributes in attr_accessible of my User model with that your first solution worked. sorry for the late reply